# Underlining a link using JavaScript after it has been clicked twice (not necessarily consecutively)

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

So far, what I've done is make a link appear underlined after being clicked using [this code](http://www.bootply.com/kOsPca430z) on Bootply. However, because I'm fairly new to JavaScript, I don't know how to amend my JS function so that for the dropdown-menu link ("2") to be underlined, one must click on it twice (not consecutively necessarily), i.e., click once to let the menu dropdown and then again to underline it. What I was thinking was to include some kind of conditional statement in that function to take into consideration the special conditions that have to be met for "2" to be underlined, but I don't know how to do this.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would attach a property to the anchor DOM object with a counter (or store the counter elsewhere, it does not matter) and increment and check the counter on every click.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to show some example code? Because I understand what you're saying, but I have no idea how to write it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YD9et/

Comment: How would I go about resetting the counter for an item after the user clicks elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EXT4q/)

```js
link.onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle('underline', ++this.dataset.clickTimes >= 2);
};
link.dataset.clickTimes = 0;
```

```css
.underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```